# VS2013 Unit testing c++ dll with CppUnitTestFramework crashes

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I have some Unit tests on a C++ dll written using   `Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework`. When I run the test It crashes and on the *Test Explorer* I see the following info

```
Result Message: Exception Code: C00000FD
Result StackTrace:  
at _chkstk() in f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\startup\i386\chkstk.asm:line 99
at SSFFCAddInMultipleAuth::SSFMultipleAuthLimitManagerTests::TestCantApplyLimitToInactiveAccount() in ....cpp:line 88
```

The code works fine when I run and use the tested code in debug or release.

According to this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d56d80e0-70f1-4ceb-b9ca-aed66e97a3d6/visual-studio-2012-unit-testing-native-c-crashes-due-to-stack-overflow?forum=vsunittest) it could be the stack space beeing different when I run the code using the *Test Explorer*

One possible solution mentioned there is to change an Registry key to increase the stack space but I can't find it on Win10/VS2013

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually related to the creation of some objects used inside of target method.